# Cannot Remove A Property From Phalcon Persistent Storage (Session Bag)

Tags: php, session, phalcon

I'm new to Phalcon PHP framework and currently I'm trying to use the persistent storage in Controller (accessed via `$this->persistent`). I know that persistent storage uses Session\Bag and according to [the API](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Session_Bag.html) I can remove a property via `remove()` or `__unset` magic method.
So, I create this little Controller to test the persistent storage:

```
<?php

class Control1Controller extends Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function cobaAction()
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        $this->persistent->destroy();
        $this->dump('anu');
        echo "Set\n";
        $this->persistent->anu = 'Aloha';
        $this->dump('anu');
        echo "Remove\n";
        $this->persistent->remove('anu');
        $this->dump('anu');
        echo "set\n";
        $this->persistent->anu = 'Aloha';
        $this->dump('anu');
        echo "assign null\n";
        $this->persistent->anu = null;
        $this->dump('anu');
        echo "set\n";
        $this->persistent->anu = 'Aloha';
        $this->dump('anu');
        echo "destroy\n";
        $this->persistent->destroy();
        $this->dump('anu');
    }

    private function dump($anu)
    {
        echo $anu.'='.var_export($this->persistent->$anu, true)."\n";
        echo 'has('.$anu.')='.var_export($this->persistent->has($anu), true)."\n";
        echo 'isset('.$anu.')='.var_export(isset($this->persistent->$anu), true)."\n";
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

When I access that action, this is the result I got:

```
anu=NULL
has(anu)=false
isset(anu)=false

Set
anu='Aloha'
has(anu)=true
isset(anu)=true

Remove
anu='Aloha'
has(anu)=true
isset(anu)=true

set
anu='Aloha'
has(anu)=true
isset(anu)=true

assign null
anu=NULL
has(anu)=true
isset(anu)=true

set
anu='Aloha'
has(anu)=true
isset(anu)=true

destroy
anu=NULL
has(anu)=false
isset(anu)=false
```

Now that's strange, I expect after calling `->remove('anu')` and setting `anu = null`, the `has()` and `isset()` would return `false`, but it didn't. Why is that?

Comment: It does look like a bug. You should report this on https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in both 1.2.5 and 1.3.0 branches, see https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/pull/1639 and https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/pull/1640